# how to automatically append custom post type entries as wp_nav_menu sublevels

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a page with Chapters and Subchapters, all subchapters are displayed on the chapter page, while each Subchapter can be commented. For better understanding I will describe the structure:

I have the following pages structure:

```
- Chapter 1
- Chapter 2
- Chapter 3
```

For each Chapter there is a hierarchical custom post type 'sub_chapters' with multiple entries (posts):

```
- Subchapter 1
  - Subchapter 1.1
  - Subchapter 1.2
- Subchapter 2
- Subchapter 3
```

The Page **Chapter 1** acts like an Overview page and gets the content from all subchapters. Like this:

```
Chapter 1 Title

- Subchapter 1 Content
- Subchapter 1 Comments
- Subchapter 1.1 Content
- Subchapter 1.1 Comments
- Subchapter 1.2 Content
- Subchapter 1.2 Comments
- Subchapter 2 Content
- Subchapter 2 Comments
- Subchapter 3 Content
- Subchapter 2 Comments
```

That's working fine so far, but now I would like to automatically append these subchapters in to the wordpress menu with anchor links.

**automatic appending**

In my template each subchapter gets an id, which is build from the slug of this entry. (eg. `id="subchapter-1-introduction"`)

My wp_nav_menu consists only of the 3 pages:

```
- Chapter 1
- Chapter 2
- Chapter 3
```

And I would like to create a menu link this (url in parenthesis) :

```
- Chapter 1 (/chapter1/)
  - Subchapter 1 Introduction (/chapter1/#subchapter1-introduction)
    - Subchapter 1.1 (/chapter1/#subchapter1-1)
  - Subchapter 2 (/chapter1/#subchapter2)
  - Subchapter 3 (/chapter1/#subchapter3)
- Chapter 2 (/chapter1/)
  ...
- Chapter 3 (/chapter1/)
```

Now I tried to build this structure by using the filter `wp_get_nav_menu_items` and alter the WP nav menu structure. But I was only able to build 1 level below the page. I was not able to build the hierarchical structure.

**no automatic appending**

So then I thought okay, we don't wan't **automatic** menu appending and it would be better to use a custom walker. Because I also need the wordpress menu classes like `current-menu-item` and so on.

I added the page/cpt structure in the Wordpress Backend Menu Section. And this gives me a nice menu, but now the permalinks are not working like expecting with anchor tags (described above)

I tried to alter the `start_el` function from `Walker_Nav_Menu` like this:

```
  if ( $depth > 0) {
    // create link to page with anchor
    $atts['href'] = $permalinkFromParentPage . '/#' $slugFromSubChapter .        
  } else {
    // were on level 0, only the page link
    $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
  }
```

But in this case, I don't know to get the $permalinkFromParentPage, because in `start_el` I only have informations about the actual menu item.

How could I fix this, or is there a better solution? I know that I can use custom links, but there are too many subchapters, so I would prefer the "automatic" menu appending with wordpress menu classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these functions to your theme's 'functions.php' (assuming 'chapter' as your custom post type).

```
class Walker_Dynamic_Submenu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array()) { // function for first level posts
        if( 100 == $item->ID ){ // replace with your menu item ID
            global $post;
            $chapters = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'chapter','posts_per_page'=>-1, 'post_parent' => 0));
            if(!empty($chapters)) {
                $output .= '<ul class="sub-menu">';
                foreach($chapters as $post): setup_postdata($post);
                    $output .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
                    $output .= get_child_posts(get_the_ID());
                    $output .= '</li>';
                endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();
                $output .= '</ul>';
            }           
        }
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
}

function get_child_posts($parent = 0) { // function to retrieve child posts
    global $post;
    $chapterschild = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'chapter','posts_per_page'=>-1, 'post_parent' => $parent));
    if(!empty($chapterschild)) {
        $outputchild .= '<ul class="sub-menu">';
        foreach($chapterschild as $post): setup_postdata($post);
            $outputchild .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
            $outputchild .= get_child_posts(get_the_ID());
        endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();
        $outputchild .= '</ul>';
    }   
    return $outputchild;
}
```

and append this to your `wp_nav_menu()` - `, 'walker' => new Walker_Dynamic_Submenu` like `wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top', 'menu_id' => 'top-menu', 'walker' => new Walker_Dynamic_Submenu ) );`.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I modified it a little bit to define the post_type with item->xfn and made some changes at the permalinks to use them as anchors. But your post was the key to my solution. Thanks!